# Application.displayalerts = false not stopping popup window

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use VBA in Excel to find and replace multiple values.  The field that is being updated has HTML text so I'm getting a window popup that says I'll lose formatting changes and when it's published back out to TFS it'll be stored as plain text.  Using Application.displayalerts = false isn't stopping that window from appearing.

Is there a way I can use code to make this go away?

[image: Warning message]

Comment: Try adding this: Application.EnableEvents = False

Comment: already tried that - no luck

Comment: actually it was disabling screen updating that I'd tried - disabling events seems to have worked.  thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addinng the below line will solve the problem.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

If you're interested, I like to use this function when I start a long process:

```
Sub SetEvents(ByVal State As Boolean)
    With Excel.Application
        .DisplayAlerts = State
        .ScreenUpdating = State
        .EnableEvents = State
        If State = True Then .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic Else .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
End Sub
```

By adding this you can turn off calcs, events, screen and alerts like this in your main sub:

```
Sub CallEvents()
    SetEvents False
    'Do some stuff
    SetEvents True
End Sub
```